# panel size is different programatically and from design

Tags: c#, winforms

This is something that has been bothering me for sometime but didn't have the time to ask.

Imagine a winform application with a Panel in it (that contains some buttons, etc)

In the Properties I can see that the panel *Size* is 381,388. Clearly.

Let's say that I put a button and in the button click method I put

```
switch(thisSize)
{
   case 0: panel1.Height= 388;
        break;
    case 1: //..... the rest
    //.....
}
```

Now when I run it and `thisSize` is 0, and the button is clicked, the size of the panel is *very different* than the original size.

In other words, when changing the size programatically, the size does not correpond to the value you set when designing it.

I wonder why is this and what is the relation between one and the other value?

EDIT: I run some checks and programatically a panel with height 388 has height 260 by code. And a panel with height 328 has height 220 by code. Why is this?

Comment: Any Anchors set?

Comment: right now it is set Anchor: Top,Left

Comment: When you find a problem, then please demonstrate it first. With screenshots and [mcve]. Small details matter: what is form layout, where you attempt to change size, how you measure its size, etc.

Comment: What is the DPIAwareness status/AutoScaleMode of your application?